# Basalz Powder glitch?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm noticing three floating Basalz powders near my base.  They weren't there a couple days ago and just suddenly appeared out of nowhere.  Doesn't seem to be anything I can do to clear them away. The are floating above a few trees nearby and don't seem to be a mob but they creep me out.

Is this a glitch in FTB Lite 3 for 1.7.10?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to use the `/cofh killall` command to get rid of them ? ([command usage here](http://teamcofh.com/docs/cofh-core/features/commands/#killall))